# How to add labels to particular positions and make a sum of values as a size of plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization

A pandas DataFrame contains, but not limited such values:

```
x      y       z    
Winter Night   2222
Spring Morning 3888
Summer Day     1111
Autumn Evening 2999
...
```

And I am sorry, I cannot provide the full dataset because of NDA

the `z` variable is used to calculate the sum and make it as a size of point on the graph

```
def Scatter(x, y, z, colour_data=None):
    f = plt.figure()
    ax.scatter(x, y, s=z)
```

[What I already have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fjwT.png)

I would like to make it as 16 points of different sizes. Basically, I want to calculate the sum of two columns and to make appropriate point sizes.

Comment: Do you need a 3D plot?  Also, what about using `.groupby(['x','y'])` to obtain the desired sums by each `x`/`y` combo before creating the plot?

Comment: 2D with different-sized points

Comment: What would be the names of the x and y axes on this 2D scatter plot?

Comment: Unless you provide people with a runnable code, required data to reproduce the figure, it is hard for people to provide an answer. Not only they have to write a code out of nowhere, but also create fake data first in the desired format. I hope you understand this is too much work. You wrote "the sum of two columns". Which columns are you referring to? You have only one column `z` which has numeric values. What two values do you want to add? Explain and include all the above points I wrote to expect a final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sheldore makes a good point about not having enough code in your example to work with, so the below may not be exactly what you're looking for.

I converted the season and time names to integers because a scatter plot cannot plot strings for the x/y axis.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'x': ['Winter','Spring','Summer','Autumn'],
    'y': ['Night','Morning','Day','Evening'],
    'z': [2222,3888,1111,2999],
})

# convert 'x' and 'y' strings to int to enable scatter plot

season_map = {
    'Winter': 0,
    'Spring': 1,
    'Summer': 2,
    'Autumn': 3,
}

time_map = {
    'Night': 0,
    'Morning': 1,
    'Day': 2,
    'Evening': 3,
}

df.loc[:,'x_int'] = df.x.map(season_map)
df.loc[:,'y_int'] = df.y.map(time_map)

ax = df.groupby(['x_int','y_int']).z.sum().reset_index()\
    .plot.scatter(x='x_int', y='y_int', s=df['z'])

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry that I am so stupid, but what is the difference between `df.groupby(['x_int','y_int']).z.sum().reset_index()\
    .plot.scatter(x='x_int', y='y_int', s=df['z'])`
and `df.plot.scatter(x='x_int', y='y_int', s=df['z'])` ?

Comment: @user73786 - I was under the impression you needed the `sum` of `z` for each `x`/`y` combo, so the `groupby` ensures this.  The non-groupby approach will produce a single scatter plot dot for each `x`/`y` combo instance (vs. the sum of ALL instances for each `x`/`y` combo).